# After successful ajax POST operation nothing happens in the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-chrome

I've checked for duplicates and none of them are strictly related to this problem.

I have the following **javascript** code

```
var value = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bank.php",
    data: {sum:money},
    cache: false,
    async: true
    }).done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  });
```

and **php** in bank.php

```
if(isset($_POST['sum']))
      {
        $money = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sum']);
        $query = "UPDATE banks SET currency = 1 WHERE amount = '.$money.'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        }
```

I receive in the browser console "success" for the ajax operation but nothing happens in the database. Take note that "currency" is a tinyint(1) and amount is an int(10) [I'm using sql tables as you might have guessed]. What am I doing wrong? (bank.php also includes the header to link to my database, so that's not the problem because I tested others queries there).

I believe the code isn't going through the `if(isset($_POST['sum']))` validation but don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the text content of the response?

Comment: Your query string is wrong, those `.` shouldn't be there

Comment: Musa, are you married yet? Just asking <3

Comment: have you tried mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); just to see if your queries are failing?

Comment: `die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());` will produce a success message in console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$query = "UPDATE banks SET currency = 1 WHERE amount = ".$money.";
```

Hope this help u.